# ScalaTest shared behaviour functions fail early

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, scalatest

I'm trying to run tests [by sharing behaviour in traits](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/sharing_tests). When I run such a test, the test always aborts early when there's a failure, not running the rest of the tests.

Here's my test:

```
trait TestBehaviour extends ShouldMatchers {
  def failEarly = fail("this fails before the test is run")
  def failEarlyAgain = fail("this also fails before the test is run")
}

class Test extends FlatSpec with TestBehaviour {

  it must behave like failEarly

  it must behave like failEarlyAgain  
}
```

If I run this in the ScalaTest IDE for Eclipse, no tests are ever shown - the RUN ABORTED text is just shown in the console:

```
*** RUN ABORTED ***
  An exception or error caused a run to abort: this fails before the test is run
```

So it looks like the first test is being run early.

What I would expect to see is both the tests are run, and fail (with different reason messages).

Comment: I have the same issue when sharing test-implementations like this. This also happens when the shared test throws an exception for other reasons: the entire test-run is aborted.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
def failEarly = fail("this fails before the test is run")
def failEarlyAgain = fail("this also fails before the test is run")
```

to

```
def failEarly() = fail("this fails before the test is run")
def failEarlyAgain() = fail("this also fails before the test is run")
```

In your version you are invoking the methods defined (because they don't have a parameter list). In my version you are passing a function created from the method (without invoking it)

Comment: Thanks! Good idea, so I tried it - but it gives exactly the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the templated test, should contain an actual test-case; like so

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec

trait TestTemplate { this: FlatSpec =>
  def failEarly() = {
    it should "fail at the right moment" in {
      fail("this fails once for each test that should behave like me")
    }
  }
}


class MyTest extends FlatSpec with TestTemplate {
  "This Test" should behave like failEarly()
  "Some other test" should behave like failEarly()
}
```

The example above seems to work for me.